# I need to take all unique data from a mysql table and put it into a new table

Tags: mysql

I have a database table (mysql 5) something like this example data:

id,name,description

> 1,**example**,test description
>
> 2,**example**,different desc
>
> 3,example**2**,another desc
>
> 4,example**3**,blah blah blah

(note that #1 and #2 have the same name, 3 and 4 are unique.

what i want to do is make a new table, with just this data:

> 1,example,test description
>
> 3,example2,another desc
>
> 4,example3,blah blah blah

ie, make sure column #2 is unique.

how can i do this easily? i have no preference as to what ones it doesnt keep

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO
    new_table(`id`, `name`, `description`)
SELECT `id`, `name`, `description` FROM old_table GROUP BY `name`
```

If you want your ID's to be re-generated, you can drop the `id` columns from that query, provided that your ID column is `auto_increment`.

Another way is to put an `UNIQUE` constraint on `name` field in `new_table` and use the `IGNORE` keyword:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO
    new_table(`id`, `name`, `description`)
SELECT `id`, `name`, `description` FROM old_table
```